# Expo react native physical device run on localhost

Tags: expo, react-native

I just `expo init` a project and start it, then scan QR code **lan connection** on dev tool with my **physical device** on **Expo Go** but it not working. I realise that expo go app running **127.0.0.1** instead of pc ip. How can I fix it ?

---

````
  Waiting on exp://127.0.0.1:19000 
  // It must be like this  Waiting on exp://192.168.1.10:19000

› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu in Expo Go
› Press d │ show developer tools
› shift+d │ toggle auto opening developer tools on startup (disabled)

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve my problem by using a QR code generator and type `exp://[MY_LAN_IP]:19000` instead of `exp://127.0.0.1:19000` then scan it.
I don't think my solution is an orthodox method, but better physical than using the emulator

Answer (score 0):

After `expo start` you should see output like this

```
› Waiting on exp://192.168.100.74:19000
 › Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

 › Press a │ open Android
 › Press w │ open web

 › Press r │ reload app
 › Press m │ toggle menu in Expo Go
 › Press d │ show developer tools
 › shift+d │ toggle auto opening developer tools on startup (disabled)

 › Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
```

As you can see in the 1st line it says `Waiting on exp://192.168.100.74:19000`

Now make sure your PC and your mobile are connected to the same Network.

Then in your `Expo Go` App scan the QR code and Done..

And Also if your are logged in both `Expo GO` App and the laptop/PC in which you are developing then you should see your Project in `Recently in Development` section.

I would suggest you to log in both devices..

**For PC:**

type `expo login` in terminal in your project folder

Type the credentials and log in.

**For Mobile:**

Sign in to your expo account in the Profile Tab.

Comment: No, like i said, expo waitting at localhost, not  **Lan connection IP**

Waiting on exp://127.0.0.1:19000
 › Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

 › Press a │ open Android
 › Press w │ open web

 › Press r │ reload app
 › Press m │ toggle menu in Expo Go
 › Press d │ show developer tools
 › shift+d │ toggle auto opening developer tools on startup (disabled)

 › Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.

Comment: Which `expo SDK` are you using??

Comment: it is `expo --version` 4.4.3 or this `dependencies "expo": "~41.0.1"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

expo start --lan if you want expo started on your lan.
expo start --localhost (127.0.0.1)