# How to make a fetch request to localhost in React Native/Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, fetch-api, deno

I'm creating a React Native/Expo app that uses [Deno](https://deno.land/) on the backend. I've created an API in the backend that I can run locally on localhost:4000. When I try to use fetch to call the API in the Expo app, however, I keep getting an error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed] at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
```

Here is how I set up the backend

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import { oakCors } from "https://deno.land/x/cors/mod.ts";
import { APP_HOST, APP_PORT } from "./config.ts";
import router from "./routes.ts";
import _404 from "./controllers/404.ts";
import errorHandler from "./controllers/errorHandler.ts";

const app = new Application();

app.use(oakCors());
app.use(errorHandler);
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());
app.use(_404);

console.log(`Listening on port:${APP_PORT}...`);
```

And how I use fetch to call the API

```
const App = () => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/something");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    ... 
  );
};
```

**Note**

- Some answers on StackOverflow suggest fetching `http://[IP_ADDRESS]:4000/something` instead of localhost. I've tried that with no luck.
- I've verified that the API is working. I can call it successfully in VSCode's Thunder Client and I can also see the data by going to `http://localhost:4000` in the browser.

Comment: I bet you are on android =) Use 10.0.2.2 from your app if so

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment @JeanJacquesGourdin. I'm not on Android, I'm on a physical iOS device.

Comment: Ah ok, may be try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394607/expo-react-native-physical-device-run-on-localhost from what I see, you should use exp and not http

Comment: You generate code snippet for fetch in Thunder Client and then compare your code

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution to this issue. I'm running my Expo app on a physical device while my server is running on my computer, on localhost. It makes sense that I'm unable to make requests to localhost on my device, because localhost is not running there.

I fixed this issue by using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), a tool that forwards localhost to a cloud URL, and fetching that URL in the app.

Comment: kudos for mentioning ngrok. This is a game changer

Answer (score 3):

Use the local IP assign to your device, like: http://192.168.20.109:port/api/x

find the local IP using the command "ipconfig" in windows or ifconfig in linux